# Firebase database sort by deeper child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Considering the following structure of the Firebase database:

- root

  - game1

    - $playerUidA

      - score: 50
    - $playerUidB

      - score: 10
    - .....
  - game2

    - $playerUidC

      - score: 20
    - $playerUidD

      - score: 30
    - .....
  - game3

    - .....

I want to run a query that will return all game nodes, where the children of each game node (the players) will be sorted based on the **score**. The game node contains the UID of each player, and each UID node contains the score of the player. I am storing other data as well, however, for the sake of this example I will be only using the score.

Can I do that with a single query? Something like 
`rootRef.child("root").orderByChild("score")`? Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

Or the only way to achieve that is by manually sorting the items on the client?

@Puf - Hope you'll answer that :)

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is rather old there might be people (like me) stumbling over it. Especially because it is pretty intuitive to structure the database in a similar way the author of the question did, to create (for example) a leaderboard system for a game. Since the answer is a bit outdated I wanted to add some things.

Some time ago the devs added the possibility to order by deeply nested children! (See [Ordering by a specified child key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key)) To do so you basically have to do the exact same thing the author did and additionally use the first part of the answer given by @adolfosrs. Basically you have to do two things:

1. Work with `.indexOn` (as described by @adolfosrs)
2. Use the `OrderByChild()` command.

To make this work on the example given by @steliosf you would have to do the following:

**First** set the .indexOn in your database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$gameId": {
      ".indexOn": "score",
      "$playerUid": {
        ...  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Second** use the Command the author of the question already used:

```
rootRef.Child("root").OrderByChild("score")
```

I would recommend that you always add a LimitToFirst() or LimitToLast() command to avoid that you pull the whole database which might be a lot of data (depending on the size of your database of course). To get for example the top 10 scores you could use:

```
rootRef.Child("root").OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(10)
```

Since the data is ordered in ascending order you need to use LimitToLast().

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the games sorted by the player score all you need to do is to work with your `.indexOn` rule.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$gameId": {
      ".indexOn": "score",
      "$playerUid": {
        ...  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will keep your data sorted in the database so when you retrieve it you will have all the data ready. But keep in mind that if you want to retrieve all the games and all the players it means you will be fetching the whole database. So you should look at the needs of your application and maybe rethink the structure.

Something that could help when scaling is to iterate over the games and retrieve a limited amount of users with `firebase.database().ref(gameId).limitToLast(10)`.

**Update**

For your example you will have all the games with the following request:

```
firebase.database().ref().once('value', snap => {
    //prints all players for each game sorted ascending.
    snap.forEach(game => {
        game.forEach(player => {
            console.log(player.val());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using `".indexOn": "score"` in the rules of the database and I can retrieve a single game node where the players are sorted by the score. The problem is that I cannot retrieve **all** game nodes, where each game node will have its children (players) sorted by the score. This cannot be done with a single query. I have to either run a different query for each game node, or manually sort the children on the client. PS. Of course, I am not trying to fetch the whole database, the structure is just an example.

Comment: Hey @MScott, did it work? Let me know if you still have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @adolfosrs. Unfortunately the players are not sorted with a single query on the games parent node. I ended up running a query for each game node in a for loop which works but it's not the optimal solution I would prefer. But it seems that there's no other solution. It's either this (multiple queries) or running one query on the games parent node and manually sorting the children of each game node on the client.