# Getting nested data from firebase and sorting it accordingly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, collections

I have a bunch of nested data stored in FirebaseRealTimeDatabase like this:

[image: Database structure]

I am able to retrieve the dataset, that is the profile and their respective scores.

```
ArrayList<String> profileNameList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> profileStatusList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<int> scoreList = new ArrayList();

databaseReference.child("players")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                    for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                        Profile profile = child.child("profile").getValue(Profile.class);
                        Scores scores= child.child("scores").getValue(Scores.class);

                        profileNameList.add(profile.getName());
                        profileStatusList.add(profile.getStatus());
                        scoreList.add(scores.getScore());
     }
  }
```

I am then using using `Collections.sort(scoreList)` to sort the scores from lowest to highest. My challenge however is, how can I associate the sorted scores(from the lowest to the highest) again with the player profile, e.g.

```
  Gavin - 15
  Rico - 40
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hope this might help [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319935/3809653)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference playersRef = rootRef.child("players");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("profile").child("name").getValue(String.class);
            long score = ds.child("score").child("baseball").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d(TAG, name + " - " + score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
playersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
Rico Hernandes - 40
Gavin Muro - 15
```

Comment: the solution you have provided does as the code I posted above. My intention was after getting the data, to sort such that I can show it in the recyclerview from the lowest to highest or vice-versa.

Comment: In this case, you should use a timestamp for all your objects so you can order according to it, like as in my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)**, right?

Comment: Thanks Alex but I found a solution. See, I needed to sort the data in ascending order. So what I did is create a `PlayerObject` and used the `Comparable` interface to assist in sorting the data.

Comment: Good, so do you think that my answer/comments helped you?