# Realtime Database query with two generated fields

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following DB structure, then I need get data filtered by "date" field. How do I do that?

```
root {
  places {
    $placeUid {
      $bookingUid {
        date: String
        name: String
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My query looks like that, and it doesn't work:

```
refPlaces = Firebase.database.getReference("places")
refPlaces.orderByChild("date").equalTo("14.10.2020").addValueEventListener(…)
```

Comment: try change this ref "refPlaces = Firebase.database.getReference("places")" for this one:
refPlaces = Firebase.database.ref("places") or set const dbr = firebase.database();
dbr.ref('palces').....

Comment: Does `orderByChild('$booking/date')` work? You are looking inside a dictionary's field. I am unsure if this is supported, and maybe you would be required to change your database format.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001994/3829706

Comment: @frunkad it seems it doesn't work with `equalTo`

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: What you're doing isn't supported - you can't have two variable child names under the path to query.

Comment: @DougStevenson oh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries work on a flat list of child nodes, where the value you order/filter on is in  a fixed path under each direct child node. Since you have two dynamic levels under `places`, you won't be able to query for it.

The solution is to create a flat list of bookings for this use-case, with each booking then having the place Uid as a property in each booking.

For more on this, see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)